# Wordpress - Gravity Forms - How to enable JavaScript validation?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, validation, gravity

Does anyone know how I can enable JS validation in a Gravity form?

I have marked each of my 3 fields as 'required', but when I submit an empty form, there is still an unnecessary trip to the server because it would seem no JavaScript validation is being performed clientside.

Here's the shortcodes I've tried:

```
    [gravityform id="1" title="false" description="true" ajax="true"]
[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="true" ajax="false"]
```

I have searched around but cannot find any info anywhere on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I use the Contact Form 7 plugin now.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't enable it, you'll have to apply classes to the form fields from the edit page and write your own JS for the validation OR use the [`validation`](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) library.

Note: I used GF almost 6 months back, I don't know if their new version supports front end validation

Comment: I thought Gravity Forms was supposed to be the bees knees - any idea why clientside validation isn't supported out-of-the-box?

Comment: No idea mate, I have done extensive add on development work using GF and I always had to write my own validations. Btw, not just client side validation, there are many other essential things missing in Gravity Forms, like `optgroups`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you implement a client-side library that validates BEFORE you post to the server, you'll never get the results that you are looking for.  There are several libraries out there.

https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate

According to the docs, you can mark your form field inputs with a required tag.  It also supports several other validation types.  Then, before you post, validate your entire form:

```
jQuery('form').validate();
```

It seems like a fairly comprehensive library.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, it seems as though Gravity Forms does not handle frontend validation out of the box

Encountered the same issue and I resolved it using the [jquerv validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin and the the following code snippet

---

in your functions.php file

```
add_action('gform_pre_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js', ['jquery'], );
});
```

then in your custom javascript file (you will have to create and enqueue one if you don't already have one)

```
(function($) {

  /**
   * Checks if the jquery-validate library is loaded
   */
  if ( !$.validator instanceof Function) {
    return;
  }

  $('form[id*=gform_]').each(function() {
    var validationOptions = {
      rules: {},
    };
    $(this).find('.gfield_contains_required input').each(function(i) {

      var ruleName = $(this).attr('name');

      if (validationOptions.rules.hasOwnProperty(ruleName)) {
        return;
      }

      validationOptions.rules[ruleName] = {
        required: true,
      };
    });
    if (Object.keys(validationOptions.rules).length > 0) {
      $(this).validate(validationOptions);
    }
  });
})(jQuery)
```

This will search each gravity form element and set the required rules for fields that have been marked as required on the form creator

Answer (score 1):

I have written a plugin you can use to enable jQuery validation for Gravity Forms. You can check the demo here. https://demos.dnesscarkey.com/jquery-validation-for-gravity-forms/

Thanks

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

When you say there isn't any validation do you mean you leave required fields open and it just reloads the page without showing the validation errors?

With the new Woocommerce 2.0.X, validation messages are broken in Gravity Forms. I had Woocommerce 1.X.X and Gravity Forms and they worked fine. Since upgrading Woocommerce the validation message is no longer shown. The form is not submitted, it just reloads the page without any indication of what is going on. I've posted a thread in Gravity Forms forum and they determined it's Woocommerce and I did some testing on an old site that had older versions of both plugins and I agree, it's Woocommerce, not Gravity Forms. Yay, Woocommerce!

Answer (score -2):

this link may helpful to you:
[enter link description here](http://www.parorrey.com/blog/front-end-development/wordpress-gravity-forms-validation-on-client-side-using-jquery/)

or you may try this after putting this code in your function.php

```
<?php function comment_validation_init() {
if(is_page(14))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#gform_1').validate({

    rules: {
      input_1: {
        required: true,
      },input_6: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

      input_3: {
        required: true,
      }
    },


    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      element.before(error);
    }

    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}}add_action('wp_footer', 'comment_validation_init');?>
```